# SQL statements in Java function

Tags: java, mysql

I am using Java and MySQL.
I have two sql statement in two separate function, one create database, another create tables.
I try to write try & catch exception block in each function, it works, like code below.

```
public class j_sql1 {
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost";
    static final String DB_URL2 = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/zxc";

    static final String USER = "root";
    static final String PASS = "";
    static Connection conn = null;
    static Statement stmt = null;

    public static void create_db()
    {
        conn = null;
        stmt = null;
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "CREATE DATABASE zxc";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally
        {
            try{
                if(stmt!=null)
                    stmt.close();
            }

            catch(SQLException se2){}

            try{
                if(conn!=null)
                    conn.close();
            }

            catch(SQLException se){
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void create_tables ()
    {
        conn = null;
        stmt = null;
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL2, USER, PASS);
            stmt = conn.createStatement(); 
            String sql =    "CREATE TABLE ABC("+
                            "abc_ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"+
                            "abc_Name varchar(50),"+
                            "PRIMARY KEY (abc_ID))";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

            stmt.close();
            conn.close(); 
        }
        catch(SQLException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally
        {
            try{
                if(stmt!=null)
                    stmt.close();
            }

            catch(SQLException se2)
            {}

            try{
                if(conn!=null)
                    conn.close();
            }

            catch(SQLException se){
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        create_db();
        create_tables();


}
}
```

But what if only one catch exception block in the main for my two try blocks in the two functions something like the code below, possible?

```
public class j_sql1 {
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost";
    static final String DB_URL2 = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/zxc";

    static final String USER = "root";
    static final String PASS = "";
    static Connection conn = null;
    static Statement stmt = null;

    public static void create_db()
    {
        conn = null;
        stmt = null;
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "CREATE DATABASE zxc";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        }
    }

    public static void create_tables ()
    {
        conn = null;
        stmt = null;
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL2, USER, PASS);
            stmt = conn.createStatement(); 
            String sql =    "CREATE TABLE ABC("+
                            "abc_ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"+
                            "abc_Name varchar(50),"+
                            "PRIMARY KEY (abc_ID))";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

            stmt.close();
            conn.close(); 
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try
        {
            create_db();
            create_tables();
        }
        catch(SQLException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally
        {
            try{
                if(stmt!=null)
                    stmt.close();
            }

            catch(SQLException se2)
            {}

            try{
                if(conn!=null)
                    conn.close();
            }

            catch(SQLException se){
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And why the variable like Connection, Statement and the functions have to be declared to static?

Thank You.

Comment: Just a side note - catching `Exception` and then doing nothing with it except for printing a stack trace is a *Really Bad Idea*.

Comment: @JonK It's still a way better idea than not printing the stacktrace.

Comment: @Kayaman Oh absolutely, *that* is an Atrociously Bad Idea! On the whole though, this seems to be an ill-conceived attempt to consolidate exception handling into one place when it *should* be separated.

Comment: @OP: If you want to leave it to the caller on how to handle the Exception rose, you better implement methods with `throws` clause. With that you need not implement explicit `try-catch-finally` blocks in those methods. Calling methods should handle exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `static` main, there is no object instance of the class j_sql1. Hence only static fields may be read.

You should do

1. Naming convention the same as 99.9 % of java users:

   ```
   class JSql1
       void createDB()
       void createTables()
   ```
2. Instantiate an object, and call functions on it:

   ```
   ... main(...) {
       JSql1 app = new JSql1();
       try {
           app.openConnection();
           app.createDB();
           app.createTables():
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           Logger.getLogger(JSql1.class.getName()).log(Level.FATAL, "...", e);
       } finally {
           app.close();
       }
   ```

   When createDB fails, there is no need to continue, hence createDB should throw the
   exception.

   Also the functions are uaseful inside a single connection, so create the connection
   separately.
3. Design decision, but at least for statements declare all as locally as possible
4. Especially try-with-resource for automatically closing helps here

   class JSql1;

   ```
   Connection conn;

   void createTables() throws SQLException {
       try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
           String sql = "CREATE TABLE ABC(" +
                        "abc_ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT," +
                        "abc_Name varchar(50)," +
                        "PRIMARY KEY (abc_ID))";
           stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: It's possible that the OP is using a JDK older than 1.7 as they're still using `Class.forName(String)`, which I don't believe you need to do in the newer JDKs.

Comment: @JonK actually I am new to database and also Java, so I just copy the code Internet, and thanks too.

Comment: @JonK Class.forName is no longer needed for JDBC4. https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/10/whats-new-in-jdbc-40.html#driver-and-connection-management